# Login-AzurermAccount in python

Tags: python, azure

I'm not a windows user thus I'm trying to get away from using powershell.

I found it really difficult to find a way to managed azure resources in different subscriptions if I have to create a service principle for each subscription.

It seems that every authentication for python requires setup of service principle and yet powershell command allows my to access multiple subscriptions based on my Tenant permissions.

- [ServicePrincipalCredentials class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/msrestazure.azure_active_directory.serviceprincipalcredentials?view=azure-python)
- [UserPassCredentials class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/msrestazure.azure_active_directory.userpasscredentials?view=azure-python)

Is there a python equivalent to `Login-AzurermAccount -Credential $Cred -TenantID $TenantID  -SubscriptionID $SubscriptionID` **Without creating a service principle?**

Comment: Have you looked at `Azure CLI` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/?view=azure-cli-latest?

Comment: Last time I checked (6 months ago) CLI it was not supporting the login to subscription through Tenant credentials.

Comment: As I know, you can use CLI login your account, and then select which subscription you need. `az login` and `az account set --subscription subscriptionId` will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the doc talking about this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/azure/python-sdk-azure-authenticate?view=azure-python#mgmt-auth-legacy

```
from azure.common.credentials import UserPassCredentials

credentials = UserPassCredentials(
    'user@domain.com',
    'my_smart_password'
)
```

Comment: You can also look at ADAL https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python, and once you find your scenario (device code, tenant, etc.) you can use an Adal wrapper to plug it into SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/azure/python-sdk-azure-authenticate?view=azure-python